# How to prevent large file size in JPEG-PDF roundtrip conversion?

Tags: pdf, compression, imagemagick, jpeg, size

TL;DR: File size doubled in roundtrip conversion between JPEG and PDF. Tools used : `poppler` and `imagemagick`

I am doing this

1. Extract images from a pdf containing only images (scanned document), via `pdfimags` of `poppler`
2. Do lossless edit (rotation) (or do nothing)
3. Convert the image into pdf, via `imagemagick`
   (I cannot use img2pdf due to some platform related issue)

```
Original 16M
Images 32M (Few kb images were deleted)
Final 33M
```

The image size is doubled while extracting. Assuming some kind of decompression took place, why they cannot be losslessly compressed back when making the PDF?

Edit:

1. Tried `-compress` with `LZW`, generated 150M file after 4x time.
2. Tried `-page A4`, no change.

Commands:

```
$ pdfimages -all Scanneddoc.pdf ./a
$ rm a-001.jpg 
$ mogrify -rotate -90 a-*.jpg
$ convert a*.jpg Rotated.pdf
```

File info:
`pdfimages -list input`

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image     260   260  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         8  0   851   851 9.91K 5.0%
   1     1 image    3184  2020  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        11  0   272   272  674K 3.6%
   2     2 image     260   260  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        16  0   851   851 9.91K 5.0%
   2     3 image    2556  2968  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        19  0   309   309  740K 3.3%
   3     4 image     260   260  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        24  0   851   851 9.91K 5.0%
   3     5 image    2500  3052  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        27  0   303   303  684K 3.1%
   4     6 image     260   260  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        32  0   851   851 9.91K 5.0%
   4     7 image    2392  1372  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        35  0   205   205  242K 2.5%
   5     8 image     260   260  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        40  0   851   851 9.91K 5.0%
   5     9 image    2360  3148  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        43  0   286   286  714K 3.3%
```

`pdfimages -list output`

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    2020  3184  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         8  0   272   272  615K 3.3%
   2     1 image    2968  2556  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        22  0   359   359 1741K 7.8%
   3     2 image    3052  2500  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        36  0   369   370 1610K 7.2%
   4     3 image    1372  2392  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        50  0   205   205  509K 5.3%
   5     4 image    3148  2360  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        64  0   381   381 1493K 6.9%
```

Clarification: The solution and comments emphasize on roation of images. To be clear the problem was large size of the images, so no rotation didn't help either. Though lossy transformation may prevent efficient compression resulting in large size, the problem was indeed in extraction part.

Comment: @KJ The original document was made by Camscanner app from Google Play Store, if that helps

Comment: My pdfimages do not take `-info` arg. It have a `-list` arg where the ppi is 851x851. There are 2 image per page, one is document, another is app watermark jpg.

Comment: You already determined with your research that the problem is with step 1. Everything else isn’t relevant to the problem and should be ignored. // I guess the line where you wrote `img2pdf` is actually the `pdfimages` invocation. Try `pdfimages -all`. Otherwise you will not get the raw images from the PDF.

Comment: @DanielB corrected. I invoked it with `-all`. Also from the `-list` the images are in jpeg format. Either it is expanding the image unnecessarily/ reencoding them or `im` is unable to compress them back

Comment: @DanielB Your suggestion is actually opposite of the solution. The solution is to use `-j` that is explicitly mention to output jpg.

Comment: I don’t see how that is the opposite. `-all` _implies_ `-j`. If it does not work, that’s a bug and you should consider reporting it.

Comment: @DanielB may be. I tried outputting png, ccitt, they are naturally far larger. My problem is solved but why different sized jpg is output I don't understand.

Comment: Here is man page `-all Write JPEG, JPEG2000, JBIG2, and CCITT images in their native
              format. CMYK files are written as TIFF files. All other images
              are written as PNG files.  This is equivalent to specifying the
              options -png -tiff -j -jp2 -jbig2 -ccitt` and `-j     Write images in JPEG format as JPEG files instead of the default
              format. The JPEG file is identical to the JPEG data stored in
              the PDF.`

Comment: You haven't stated if the size of the images you have was before or after the rotation. Also AFAIK `mogrify -rotate -90` certainly isn't a lossless edit: it will uncompress the JPEG to a bitmap, rotate it, and then recompress it with possibly different JPEG settings (e.g. quality). Changing the EXIF orientation, or controlling the rotation in the PDF, is probably a better option.

Comment: @jcaron The size change is negligible. The problem is not related to it, since it persists even if I do nothing. TIL it is lossy. Next time I'll edit EXIF. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-j (write JPEG images as JPEG files)` instead of `-all (equivalent to -png -tiff -j -jp2 -jbig2 -ccitt)` makes sensible output in `pdfimages`.

N.B: Anyone looking for how to efficiently rotate the pdf pages/images in-place see this question in [U&LSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394065/command-line-how-do-you-rotate-a-pdf-file-90-degrees)

Comment: This is not a good answer. Using it where? You mentioned few apps. Any kind of explantation would be nice a well.

Answer (score 2):

PDF and JPEG are often used together. Since a JPEG is usually stored in its original format as a whole component insertion. Whereas, TIF, GIF, PNG and any other pixelated images get significantly transformed.

Thus the extracted JPG will often be inserted at a different density to it source and on extraction without dpi it will be byte perfect (100% roundtripping).

One advantage of PDF is it ignores EXIF orientation and spins the image at any amount of degrees at any scale. So rotating a page does not change the image in any way the extracted image will be exactly the same hash on insert and extract.

However image lossless rotation has to produce collateral damage to a JPEG image internals in different ways.

The least damage is if there is an EXIF block with orientation then simply alter those bytes. But if you want to re-orientate the pixels its inevitably going to destroy something. For example one image through different lossless JPEG rotators.

```
source image A4 @ 200 dpi

2339 x 1653  Pixels (3.87 MPixels) (1.41)
29.7 x 21.0 cm; 11.69 x 8.27 inches
JPEG, CMYK, quality: 59, subsampling ON (2x2)
16,7 Million colours max (32 BitsPerPixel)
40165 colours used
502.58 KB (514,642 Bytes)

---------------------------
JPG Transformation error: "Perfect" operation is not possible.
Bad image dimensions (not multiples of 16)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
Here are 3 different "lossless" application solutions

Commercial (no names)
undercrop MCU (1653 and cut -5)

1648 x 2339  Pixels (3.85 MPixels) (0.70)
20.9 x 29.7 cm; 8.24 x 11.69 inches
JPEG, CMYK, quality: 59, subsampling ON (2x2)
16,7 Million colours max (24 BitsPerPixel)
40159 colours used
450.43 KB (461,237 Bytes)

IrfanView Graphics app
overcrop MCU (1653 and pad +11)

1664 x 2339  Pixels (3.89 MPixels) (0.71)
21.1 x 29.7 cm; 8.32 x 11.69 inches
JPEG, CMYK, quality: 59, subsampling ON (2x2)
16,7 Million colours max (24 BitsPerPixel)
40160 colours used
452.28 KB (463,131 Bytes)

Open Source Independent JPEG Group 
jpegcrop (retain dimensions)

1653 x 2339  Pixels (3.87 MPixels) (0.70)
21.0 x 29.7 cm; 8.27 x 11.69 inches
JPEG, CMYK, quality: 59, subsampling ON (2x2)
16,7 Million   (24 BitsPerPixel)
40159 colours used
504.13 KB (516,231 Bytes)
```

So clearly the best is the Open Source offering as developed over the longest time. However the number of colours was reduced in the transformation but file size went up a minimal amount.

So the correct way to round trip a JPEG in a PDF for rotation is do not alter the image only alter its EXIF or simpler rotate the PDF page and reuse in a new file.

So here is a run the Source 200 dpi JPEG is always the same never a byte changed but the landscape scan was reduced a page size (A4 to A5) and rotated to portrait before save as PDF.

[image]

so shown above the JPEG is extracted by pdfimages -all and bounces back to its natural state  (200 dpi A4) then we can re insert to a page and it will be perfectly same. the only difference is the PDF carrier has a few extra bytes to describe the new layout.

515426 has been increased to 515482 and even that could be compressed to a few bytes smaller as it was a CMD file to do the conversion as textual using OS commands.
[image]

SUMMARY there is NO CHANGE to the 200 dpi image whatsoever. The reported image pixel PPI density differs because of SCALE. BOTH images are UPRIGHT, BOTH pages are UPRIGHT.

It is the image RENDER IS ROTATED within the pages of different object ratios.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed resonse. This will be helpful for me in future. However the problem seems to be in extraction part.

Comment: How to understand if it is bitmap or jpeg (seems to be jpeg).?If it is jpeg and expands due to extraction,  why cannot be put back into another identical pdf having similar size of original pdf.